# Dynamic table malfunction in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a simple table structure as provided below.

Now when I want to add a row dynamically after a specified row, the table malfunctions and the click event stops working.

When the .append() is used, everything works as expected.
However, when I am trying to add a row at a specified location, say
I click '+' at row 2, that means, I have to add a new row between current 2 and 3. This is not working, and on the top of that, the click event stops responding.

```js
$('tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button][class=add]', function() {
  var $tr =
    $(
      "<tr>" +
      "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
      "<td><input class='add' type='button' value='+'/></td>" +
      "<td><input class='del' type='button' value='-'/></td>" +
      "</tr>"
    );
  var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  alert(index);
  //$('tbody').append($tr);  //---> works perfectly
  $('tbody').eq(index).after($tr); //---> Not working properly
  /*
    click not responding for the newly added row.
  */
});

$('tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button][class=del]', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Ingredient</td>
      <td>Measurement</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class='add' type='button' value='+' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class='del' type='button' value='-' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've also created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbc1992/32sjhrk2/9) for it.

Comment: Well, some one has downvoted all the posts. Kindly state the reason for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('tbody').eq(index).after($tr)` in your code is actually adding the new row outside `tbody`. you can change it to `$('tbody tr').eq(index).after($tr)`

```js
$('tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button][class=add]', function() {
  var $tr =
    $(
      "<tr>" +
      "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
      "<td><input class='add' type='button' value='+'/></td>" +
      "<td><input class='del' type='button' value='-'/></td>" +
      "</tr>"
    );
  var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  alert(index);
  //$('tbody').append($tr);  //---> works perfectly
  $('tbody tr').eq(index).after($tr); //---> Not working properly
  /*
    click not responding for the newly added row.
  */
});

$('tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button][class=del]', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Ingredient</td>
      <td>Measurement</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class='add' type='button' value='+' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class='del' type='button' value='-' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$('tbody').eq(index).append($tr);
```

change to:

```
$('tbody tr').eq(index).after($tr);
```

The snippet:

```js
$('tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button][class=add]', function(){
    var $tr =
            $(
                    "<tr>"+
                    "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
                    "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
                    "<td><input class='add' type='button' value='+'/></td>"+
                    "<td><input class='del' type='button' value='-'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>"
            );
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    $('tbody tr').eq(index).after($tr);
});

$('tbody').on('click', 'input[type=button][class=del]', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Ingredient</td>
        <td>Measurement</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text'/></td>
        <td><input type='text'/></td>
        <td><input class='add' type='button' value='+'/></td>
        <td><input class='del' type='button' value='-'/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: $('tbody tr').eq(index).after($tr); --> This was the issue. Not the class. I did add the class to the dynamic row buttons.